# What is the difference between exposing docker port and creating bridge(or overlay)?

Tags: networking, docker, containers, port, cluster-computing

I've started to work with Docker recently, so the question might be strange. The point is that I need to deploy cluster using containers and my main concern is next: what will be more suitable - just to expose ports of all containers to the machine's ports or to use bridge(or overlay)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Port exposing** is intended to communicate docker container cluster with the **outside**.

**Docker network** is intended to communicate docker containers with each other **inside** of the cluster.

Therefore this is bad practice to communicate containers with each other via port exposing to host machine.

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful advice!